# Is an Elf Fighter 1 different from a Human Fighter 1 in terms of the level-up bonuses?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, fighter, character-advancement

Is an Elf Fighter 1 different from a Human Fighter 1 in D&D 5e in terms of the level-up bonuses?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Have you read the PHB/basic rules, specifically the sections on choosing a race and on character advancement beyond 1st level?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No

As detailed in Player's Handbook, p. 15, under the heading *Beyond 1st Level*, characters who gain levels only gain class features, and hit dice/hit points. Your race determines what you have to start with, but you generally don't gain new racial abilities upon level up.

The exception is any racial ability that is gained at a higher level, such as the drow ability to cast *faerie fire* once they reach 3rd level.